# C\C++ default ordinal IC String sorting in C# without boilerplate?

Tags: c#, string, sorting

So I have a sting collection that I get from C++ app and its string sorting has some slight differences against default Ordinal IgnoreCase in C# (I assume weightables differ?) For example, it sorts:

```
PB_DT_word
PBDT
```

having `_` higher position while in .NET

```
PBDT
PB_DT_word
```

`_` will be way lower than `D` or some other special symbols.

Now, I know at least one way to implement custom string sorting rules in C#/.NET, thanks to google, but the amount of boilerplate literally makes me sick. **Is there a simpler, smaller on scale, and quicker way?**

Comment: Could you show what you *have* found? It's hard to suggest something simpler and smaller without knowing what it needs to be simpler and smaller than. Have you worked out the *precise* sorting rules you need to implement?

Comment: I found some obtuse implementation of your own, basically, weight table, which is nuts. I mean, if I was making a large-scale product as abase for other products - sure, but this is miniscule tool with a few conditions like this so it just unnecessary. The default OrdinalIgnoreCase in .NET/C# is fine, I just need to adjust  a few special symbols to make them above (as in below in the value but above in Ascending) the basic 127-ANSI letters. So ideally like some extension of OrdinalIC without rewriting it.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know which implementation you mean. But I wouldn't expect to be able to do this just by taking the existing implementation and adding a tweak. Given that it's ordinal - and assuming you don't need to handle non-basic-multilingual-plane characters, which make life harder - it shouldn't be too hard, but without knowing what you've tried or seen, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Well, what would be your approach off the top of your head?

Comment: *If* you don't need surrogate pair support, I'd go one character at a time. Then you just need to work out how to compare two characters.

Comment: "surrogate pair support"?

Comment: Yes - support for surrogate pairs: two UTF-16 code units used to form a single code point not in the Basic Multilingual Plane (characters above U+FFFF). Typically for emojis.

Comment: Given https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8, it's possible that `OrdinalIgnoreCase` doesn't actually sort by Unicode code point, but by UTF-16 code unit anyway, in which case you *may* be able to ignore that.